# Preserve/restore matplotlib context after plt.show()

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Problem**

I would like to show chart after each alternation. The problem is that after `plt.show()` the context is cleared.

**Question**

How to preserve/restore context of `matplotlib` after `plt.show()`, so I can add new data, and then show updated chart?

*Note: I did not need to update chart in place, I would like to have 2 charts.*

**Example**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()

# how to restore context here, so the second graph will also contain first one data
plt.plot([3,2,1])
plt.show()
```

| Result | Expected |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: *Note: I did not need to update chart in place, I would like to have 2 charts.* But you are showing a combined graph as expected graph

Comment: Nope, the function plt.show() is invoked twice, so it is not subplot.

Comment: You can't redraw a given Artist (e.g. a Line2D in this case) from an existing plot onto a new plot